# Is there any FREE GUI Tool for generating Certificates for PayPal Encrypted Website Payments?

Tags: paypal, openssl

I am looking for a FREE GUI Tool for generating certificates for PayPal Encrypted Website Payment Buttons. I am not comfortable at all using a command line tool like OpenSSL, rather, if a tool can encapsulate that OpenSSL and give me a nice GUI, I would love that. Is there anything like this ?

I need for Widows 7 (x64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully SpiceLogic 'PayPal Certificate Generator for Encrypted Website Payments' is the one you are looking for.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/PayPal-Certificate-Generator-for-Encrypted-Website-Payments-9

It is a tool that utilizes OpenSSL but gives you an easy Graphical User Interface for generating the certificates. It is free too.