# Paypal Certificate Integration to PHP/CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn

I saw this link for Paypal Certificate generator. [Is there any FREE GUI Tool for generating Certificates for PayPal Encrypted Website Payments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380044/is-there-any-free-gui-tool-for-generating-certificates-for-paypal-encrypted-webs/25614792?noredirect=1#comment40016089_25614792)

how can I apply my certificates, private key and OpenSSL to this code? can someone have a tutorial, links or sample code for this?

```
  var $test = array(
    'business'      => 'asdfghjk@gmail.com',         // 'live_email@paypal.com', //Your Paypal email account
    'server'        => 'https://www.paypal.com',        // Main paypal server.
    // 'notify_url'    => 'http://www.qwertyuiop.com/paypal/paypals/add',
    'notify_url'    => 'http://localhost/cakephp/paypals/add',
                                                        // 'http://test.yoursite.com/paypal_ipn/process',
                                                        // Notify_url... set this to the process path of your
                                                        // paypal_ipn::instant_payment_notification::process action
    'currency_code' => 'USD',                           // Currency
    'lc'            => 'US',                            // Locality
    'item_name'     => 'Paypal_IPN',                    // Def_ault item name.
    'amount'        => '15.00',                         // Default item amount.
    'encrypt'       => true                           // Set to true to enable encryption
);

var $encryption_default = array(
    'cert_id'       => 'V2B7XWQF963HA',                              // Certificate ID (gotten after certificate uploaded to paypal)
    'key_file'      => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\webroot\files\cert_key.pem',     // Absolute path to Private Key File
    'cert_file'     => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\webroot\files\paypal_cert.pem',    // Absolute path to Public Certificate file
    'paypal_cert_file' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\webroot\files\paypal_cert.pem',   // Absolute path to Paypal certificate file
    'openssl'       => 'C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl',            // OpenSSL location
    'bn'            => 'PaypalIpn.Paypal',     // Build Notation
);
```

btw, I'm using Paypal.IPN plugin in CakePHP. **Thanks!**